# local.xml - How Can I install Magento Files in a Shared Hosting and my Database (2GB+) in my Dedicated Server?

Tags: mysql, local.xml, server

I have my Magento files (app, lib, media, var, etc..) in a Shared Hosting, How can I edit the local.xml to comunicate the platform with a remote database? In the remote server I'm running MySQL 5.1.73 with my database (over 2GB in products, categories, orders, etc...)

Local Files Server --------> Remote MySQL Server

Please I need help to solve this. Regards.

Comment: Care to explain, *why* you need this? Because it sounds like a terribly stupid idea.

Comment: I need this because in my server I can't install new themes, always I get the table XXX no exists after of upload the theme files, I've tested in Godaddy and works fine. The problem is my server, I have 12 hrs. to solve this :(

Comment: If it's not just for personal use / testing, Godaddy shared hosting is not an appropiate hosting plan for Magento. I strongly recommend finding a hoster who offers managed hosting. If they are specialized in Magento, that's a big plus.

Answer (score 1):

If you change the host in your local.xml to point to your remote server and enable remote access in your database for this account, then you will be fine. But why not put all your files on your dedicated server too? If they are not in the same datacenter, it might be slower.

Comment: Thank you for relpy, I can't put the all files in the Dedicated Server because my server not are optimized for hosting. Actually in godaddy I have a 95% in performance (tested in GT Metrix & Pingdoom) In my server I get 60%. Excuse me, How can I enable the remote access in phpmyadmin? in the local.xml, only with the IP is suficient? Regards.

Comment: @David if your server is not optimized for hosting, why not ask it to be optimized? Shared hosting provides you resource limits. But to set the host in PHPMyAdmin, if you have the right permissions on the home page you should see a tab privileges. There add a user with the hostname of your shared hosting server.

Comment: @David If this help you; feel free to select my answer.